# How can I allow one space in a regular expression

Tags: regex

The following Regex checks for a number which starts with 6, 8 or 9 and has to be exactly 8 digits long.

```
/^(6|8|9)\d{7}$/
```

Now I want to accept one space in between digits as well, but don't know where to start.

For example both `61234567` and `6123 4567` should be allowed, but only the first one passes my current regex.

Can you help me create it?

Comment: Where is the space allowed to be at in your number? In the middle? Or in any place?

Comment: `^(?!.*(?:\s\d+){2})[689](?:\s?\d){7}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/y5a1kV/1

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?!.*(?:\s\d+){2})[689](?:\s?\d){7}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y5a1kV/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?:\s\d+){2})`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, after any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible occurrences, there are two occurrences of a whitespaces followed with 1+ digits
- `[689]` - `6`, `7` or `9`
- `(?:\s?\d){7}` - seven occurrences of an optional whitespace followed with a single digit
- `$` - end of string.

To allow leadign/trailing whitespace, add `\s?` (1 or 0) or `\s*` (0 or more) right after `^` and before `$`.

To allow a single 1+ more whitespace chunk in the digit string, use

```
^(?!.*(?:\s+\d+){2})[689](?:\s*\d){7}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y5a1kV/2).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regular expression

```
/^[689](?:\d{7}|(?=.{8}$)\d* \d+)$/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/IjQSss/1/)

We can make this self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*:

```
/
^            # match beginning of line
[689]        # match '6', '8' or '9'
(?:          # begin non-capture group
  \d{7}      # match 7 digits
  |          # or
  (?=.{8}$)  # require the remainder of the line to have 8 chars
  \d*\ \d+   # match 0+ digits, a space, 1+ digits 
)            # end non-capture group
$            # match end of line
/x           # free-spacing regex definition mode
```